# How to save Data In Database to the controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to save Data In Database to the controller.i am using jquery to get data from the textbox. please help me.

Contactcontroller.cs

```
public ActionResult Create(string Name, string Company, string
 Regarding, string Email, string Phone, string Message)         {
           string body = "Name: " + Name + "<br>" + "\nCompany: " + Company + "<br>" + "Regarding: " + Regarding + "<br>" + "Email: " +
      Email + "<br>" + "Phone: " + Phone + "<br>" + "Message: " + Message;
                  try
     { 
   // code 
    } 
     catch
     {
}
```

jquery.js

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
 var data = { Name: $("#txtbxName").val(), Company: $("#txtbxCompany").val(), Regarding:
            $("#ddlRegarding").val(), Email: $("#txtbxEmail").val(), Phone: $("#txtbxPhone").val(), Message:
            $("#txtarMessage").val()
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Contact/Create",  // the method we are calling
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),

            dataType: "html",
            success: function (result) {

                $("#txtarMessage").val("");
                alert(result);
                // Or if you are returning something
                alert('I returned... ' + result.WhateverIsReturning);
            },
            error: function (result) {

                alert('Thanks for sending info');
                location.reload();

                return false;

            }
        });
    });
```

i am getting data to the textbox using jquery.
now i want to save the whole data in the database through Controller.

Comment: Confused, are you trying to construct a view from data in the DB? If you are then you really need to read the mvc tutorials.

Comment: Your code does not look like `javascript` or `php` or `jquery` to me.

Comment: your code is .net cs file and tag is php ?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to save the string 'body' in a database?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery

```
$.post('/Controller/Create', { Name: $('#Name').val(), Company: "Company", Regarding: "", Email: "",Phone: "",Message: ""}, function (data) {

});
```

Controller Action

```
public JsonResult Create(string Name, string Company, string Regarding, string Email, string Phone, string Message)
{
string body = "Name: " + Name + "<br>" + "\nCompany: " + Company + "<br>" + "Regarding: " + Regarding + "<br>" + "Email: " +
  Email + "<br>" + "Phone: " + Phone + "<br>" + "Message: " + Message;

return Json(body, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```